# Does "Process Monitor" work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process, process-monitor

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

doesn't explicitly say it does support Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Download the latest version and it works fine.

```
Client: Windows XP SP2 and higher.
```

Comment: ok if I save to a file, then install some software, how can I see a diff to see what changed?

Comment: ehh, process monitor is only good at seeing "as it happens" you really want to go in to registry editor and export local machine and local user, then do the same after installing and finally use a compare tool to see the difference... or one of the other options I wrote in my post on the other thread.

Comment: Ty starting a pmon logging session _before_ you start the installer, and pmon will log its' activity. Just note that pmon will collect _a lot_ of data...

Comment: +1, correct for "*a lot*", remember to use the filter feature.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of procmon that works for me on Windows 7 x64 SP1 is v3.86.

You must install KB4474419 and KB4490628.

For downloading the KB update use:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/

For more info about the SHA2 updates:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus-64d1c82d-31ee-c273-3930-69a4cde8e64f